# NGRX Entity State changes causes other slices to update

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, state-management, ngrx-entity

I have multiple EntitySates in the same slice of state. When I update with one of my entity adapters, the selector observable of the other EntityStates also gets triggered, although the selector is not accessing the updated slice of state. Is this behaviour expected?

State:

```
export interface ComputerState extends EntityState<Computer> {
}

export interface PersonState extends EntityState<Person> {
}

export interface DataState {
    computer: ComputerState;
    person: PersonState;
}
```

The following reducer action causes the person selector observable to emit a new value:

```
on(Actions.updateComputerExample, (state, { id }) => {
        return {
            ...state,
            computer: computerAdapter.updateOne(
                { id: id, changes: { name: 'test' } },
                state.computer
            ),
        };
    }),
```

Person Selector:

```
export const selectPersons= createSelector(
    selectState,
    state=> state? personAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll(state.person) : null
)
```

Does someone have a solution to this?

Comment: what does 'selectState'  look like?

Comment: export const selectState= createFeatureSelector<State>('xxxx');    xxxx stands for my state constant

Answer (score 1):

You should be coding your reducer like this:

```
on(Actions.updateComputerExample, (state, { id }) => {
   return computerAdapter.updateOne(
      { id: id, changes: { name: 'test' } },
      { ...state });
}),
```

Comment: this does not work, because the second parameter of updateOne only accepts the computer enity state. ...state would be the whole state.

Comment: if it is a reducer for computer, then it should never be the whole state.

Comment: I have multiple entity states in the same state -> the reducer is, in the case shown in the question, for computer and person

Comment: Kind of similar to: https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/multiple-entities-in-a-single-ngrx-8-state-ed5fd082c3f0 , but like I said in the questions I have problems with the selectors.